# How expensive is fmod in terms of processor time?

Tags: c++, math

In my game, I need to ensure that angles do not exceed 2 pi. so I use `fmod(angle,TWO_PI);`

Is this noticeably expensive to do about 100 times per second?

Comment: You should not be asking this question. You should just implement it, and see how does performance-wise. Then you would use a profiler to search for performance-bottlenecks in your application. If you then find that `fmod` takes a lot of time, you can come and ask for alternatives. Don't do premature optimization.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

100 times per second? That's almost zero, you shouldn't trouble yourself.

Even if fmod takes 100 clock cycles - that's 10,000 cycles/Sec. For 1 1GHz CPU - that's 0.001% CPU.

BTW: why do you want to do fmod of TWO_PI? If you're going to take sin() or cos() - you can skip it.

Comment: Because I need to check if it is above or below the min and max angles. So I cant do > if it is 7, which would actually be like 0.8

Answer (score 1):

If you want to ensure that angles do not *exceed* 2pi radians, you should use `angle < TWO_PI`. Using [fmod](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cmath/fmod/) will give you the remainder, which is useful if you want to find the actual angle and ignore multiple revolutions, but doesn't give you any information about which is greater.

Using `<` is very efficient, and as long as you aren't doing it 100,000+ times a second or don't have a lot of other code involved in the loop you should be fine. `fmod` is a fair bit more expensive as it involves division AND floating-point arithmetic, but 100 times per second is still almost negligible on most modern hardware, so I doubt you'll have much trouble at all. If you're still worried, do some tests. If you need help interpreting the tests or have other specific questions, post the code and we'll help you analyze them. :D

Comment: `<` may be efficient, but the associated conditional (and therefore the associated branch-prediction penalty) will not be so efficient.  I don't know how it compares to `fmod` though.